# PostgreSQL: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm new to SQL and I get the following error on ***postgres*** while running

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE birth_day LIKE '%-10-%';
```

Error:

```
Error: operator does not exist: date ~~ unknown
Error Code: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Employee table:

```
id  f_name  l_name  birth_day
------------------------------
100 David   Wallace 1967-11-17
101 Jan     Levinso 1961-05-11
102 Michael Scott   1964-03-15
103 Angela  Martin  1971-06-25
104 Kelly   Kapoor  1980-02-05
105 Stanley Hudson  1958-02-19
106 Josh    Porter  1969-09-05
107 Andy    Bernard 1973-07-22
108 Jim     Halpert 1978-10-01
```

The intention is to filter out people who are born in October using LIKE. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: LIKE only works on strings (text), not for dates, timestamps or numbers

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thanks!